# Adding a user to "IIS Manager Permissions" using PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-10

I have a PowerShell script that installs IIS & WebDeploy among other things on  a Windows Server 2019. I am aware that I can grant permissions to IIS Manager Permissions using:

`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Management")  [Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthorization]::Grant($deploymentAccount, $ApplicationName, $false)`

Most of the other script uses the newer IISAdministration cmdlets. Is there a *newer* way of granting the permissions that is a little nicer to read?

Comment: "nicer to read" is subjective. Why the above is not nice to read?

Comment: Fair comment. In comparison to how the newer IIS Administration cmlets are implemented. I guess the question should have been, is there a newer API to achieve the same